# How do I pass information in a multiform program using text boxes and list boxes?

Tags: c#, listbox

What I was wondering was, how do I pass information from multiple text boxes through a submit button on one form, into a list box onto a different form. I am using c# and also ASP.NET, and need this for both of programs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well suppose this is your form1 (multiple text boxes,button event):

```
public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
    List<string> liststrings = new List<string>();
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        liststrings.Add(textBox1.Text);
        liststrings.Add(textBox2.Text);
        liststrings.Add(textBox3.Text);

        var form2 = new Form2(liststrings);
        form2.Show();
        this.Hide();

    }
```

and then you have you second from where the listbox resides(Listbox control)...

```
public Form2(List<string> lista)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        listBox1.DataSource = lista;
    }
```

I made this example on string components, you can modify this to your own requirements ...
The whole idea is to pass a list object and then you display this list inside a .net ListBox.